# What's the estimated ETA on Evernote API key activation?

Tags: evernote

We've had our app key submitted for production using the online form for a couple of days. So far, zero communication from Evernote. Are there guidelines to what the expected approval timeline looks like to help with PM setting expectations?

Following another SO post, we've also tried to contact devsupport@evernote.com but no reply either.

Comment: 9 days later and still zero communication from evernote. pretty terrible developer experience.

Answer (score 0):

Not an official ETA by any stretch, but it took 2 days for my key to be activated.